# Pandas: How to Convert Column to List Then Use Explode Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
product_name                                            price                                                    variations
Cream Deluxe Gold (615g)    [ '130.00', '255.00', '500.00', '995.00', '8200.00']          [ '6 PIECES', '12 PIECES', '24 PIECES', '48 PIECES', '1 PALLET']
FastGas                     [ '140.00', '275.00', '535.00', '1050.00', '8400.00']          [ '6 PIECES', '12 PIECES', '24 PIECES', '48 PIECES', '1 PALLET']
```

I want to convert the price and variation columns to lists so I can explode them. My expected dataframe will look like this:

```
product_name                    price         variations
Cream Deluxe Gold (615g)        130.00       6 PIECES
Cream Deluxe Gold (615g)        255.00      12 PIECES
```

I tried this code:

```
df = df.explode(['price','variations'])
```

and I'm getting my original dataframe and not my expected dataframe.

Comment: This is not reproducible as the code works fine. Are you the datatype of the price and variation columns is `list` and not `str`?

Comment: can you show how you set your dataFrame? I set the variable ```df``` like this : df = pd.DataFrame({
    "product_name": ["Cream Deluxe Gold (615g)", "FastGas"],
    "price": [[ '130.00', '255.00', '500.00', '995.00', '8200.00'], [ '140.00', '275.00', '535.00', '1050.00', '8400.00']],
    "variations": [[ '6 PIECES', '12 PIECES', '24 PIECES', '48 PIECES', '1 PALLET'],[ '6 PIECES', '12 PIECES', '24 PIECES', '48 PIECES', '1 PALLET']]
}) so it's work perfectly fine for me

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_9VvP54CAJJSvtsArZiTMMfMzACDS11/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` parses the list in the columns as a string by default. Hence you're not able to explode the columns. To read the columns as lists, you can define a custom converter that applies [pd.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', converters={'price': pd.eval, 'variations': pd.eval})
```